# Issue with MySQL query (Types, maybe?)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am developing a database to emulate a order-by-mail movie service. Currently, I am having a problem regarding this query:

```
select *
from  items i, casted_by c
where i.itemID = c.itemID
```

My tables are defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE Items(
itemID                    VARCHAR(15),
released_date             DATE,
number_copies_available   INT,
title                     VARCHAR(50),

PRIMARY KEY(itemID)
);

CREATE TABLE Casted_By(
castID           VARCHAR(15),
itemID           VARCHAR(15),

PRIMARY KEY(castID, itemID),

FOREIGN KEY (castID) REFERENCES Actors(castID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Movies(itemID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I have populated these tables using CSV files containing

These in Items:

```
300000,2008/05/23,5,Iron Man 1
300001,2010/05/13,15,Iron Man 2
300002,2012/06/20,12,Iron Man 3
300003,2009/01/22,5,Hangover 1
300004,2011/05/01,15,Hangover 2
300005,2013/06/29,10,Hangover 3
300006,1997/08/14,15,Titanic
300007,2014/09/06,5,Intersteller
300008,2014/02/19,20,Birdman
300009,2014/04/14,20,American Sniper
```

These in Casted_By:

```
700000,300000
700000,300001
700000,300002
700001,300003
700001,300004
700001,300005
700001,300009
700002,300003
700002,300004
700002,300005
700003,300003
700003,300004
700003,300005
700004,300006
700004,300023
700004,300026
700005,300007
700006,300008
700007,300011
700008,300010
700009,300012
700010,300014
700011,300015
700012,300020
700013,300017
700013,300018
700013,300019
700014,300017
700014,300018
700014,300019
700015,300016
700016,300021
700016,300008
700017,300022
700018,300023
700018,300029
700019,300024
```

When I execute the query, only one row appears! (Which happens to be Kate Winslet Casted in Titanic). But many others should appear, like the first one (which is Robert Downey Jr. in Iron Man).

Strangely, if I try

```
select *
from  Casted_By c
where c.itemID = 300000
```

I am returned the correct results, but if I try

```
select *
from  Casted_By c
where c.itemID = '300000'
```

the query returns null!

This is not the same case if I replace c.itemID with c.castID and use 700000, with or without single quotes it works.

Comment: Try using a numeric type for the `castID`.  There could be whitespace which is causing the join to fail (except oddly for Kate Winslet).

Comment: What datatypes do `Actors.castID` and `Movies.itemID` have?

Comment: @Drudge, the answer to your question is in the actual question.

Comment: @DanBracuk Where exactly? I asked this because the datatypes can vary between the current table's column and the referenced table's column when using a foreign key. I cannot be sure it's a `varchar(15)`.

Comment: @Drudge, in the create table commands.

Comment: @DanBracuk For the tables `Actors` and `Movies`? I can see `Items` and `Casted_By` only or am I that blind?

Comment: @Drudge, I see `CREATE TABLE Casted_By(
castID           VARCHAR(15),
itemID           VARCHAR(15),` and `CREATE TABLE Items(
itemID                    VARCHAR(15),`

Comment: @DanBracuk I still don't get it what that has to do with the `Actors` and `Movies` table. Even if `Casted_By.castID` is type of `varchar(15)` and references `Actors.castID`, `Actors.castID` must not have necessarily the data type `varchar(15)`, too. That's why I asked for the data types. I encountered myself that MySQL behaved odd when the data type of the local table's column and the referenced table's column were different.

Comment: @Drudge, the point is that I see all the relevant datatypes and you asked a question about 2 of them.

Comment: Are you trying to all the actors who appear in a certain film or all the films that a certain actor has appeared in?

Comment: What happens when you run `select * from  Casted_By c where hex(c.itemID) = hex('300000')`. I have SQLFiddle here for anyone else to continue with data provided: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c10ef/4